# Windows combine WiFi sharing + ethernet

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, lan

I'm using a 4G dongle to connect my main PC to the internet, but I have multiple devices so I share my 4G connection using Connectify. I'm using this software instead of the built in adhoc network, because of stability purposes. I've tried using the adhoc network, but it was very unstable - dropped connections, long connection times, poor LAN transfer speeds etc.

My main issue was my mediacentre PC which was also using the shared wifi connection, but streaming full hd videos from my main PC resulted in laggy videos. So I connected my mediacentre PC via ethernet cable to my main PC. It works but it's not perfect.

What I did, was I shared my 4G connection to my ethernet port, because trying to share the connection via the WiFi connection didn't work. Connectify "takes" the internet from the 4G dongle and streams it via the WiFi card, and using the WiFi card as the source of sharing just didn't work.

My question is.. How do I get my mediacentre PC that's connected via ethernet cable, to be on the same lan as all other wireless devices? Currently the mediacentre pc and my main one share a LAN, and my main pc and all other wireless devices share a different LAN, so all wireless devices cannot see the mediacentre pc, and it cannot see them.

Update:

This is how my current setup looks like

[image]

So my 4G connection is shared via WiFi using Connectify to increase stability. My mediacentre is connected via ethernet cable into my main pc. What I want to achieve - is have only one LAN, right now I have two..

Comment: By "ad-hoc" do you mean you tryed the `netsh wlan set hostednetwork `commands ?  This commands set your Wifi card in Access Point mode which is diffrent from ad-hoc... and probably more stable.

Comment: Any way, I'mnot sure to understand what you mean. Can you edit your post describing separatly : 1) What you want to do 2) What you tryed to do, 3) What you think you have to do

Comment: I'll try to make a diagram/flowchart of my setup and I'll update my question asap

Comment: I've done superficial researches and that doesn't seem possible to do this way. The only way would be to use a hybrid Wifi/ethernet switch connected via ethernet to your PC which would act as a router, sharing its 4G connection. Windows cannot act as a switch, even if there are hackish way to build something that could work after weeks of hacking it...